# Can Prodigy's skill expertise apply to the same skill the PC just became proficient in?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, skills, proficiency

The Prodigy feat (from Xanathar's Guide to Everything) states the following:

> *Prerequisite: Half-elf, half-orc or human*
>
> You have a knack for learning new things. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - You gain one skill proficiency of your choice, one tool proficiency of your choice, and fluency in one language of your choice.
> - Choose one skill in which you have proficiency. You gain expertise with that skill, which means your proficiency bonus is doubled for any ability check you make with it. The skill you choose must be one that isn't already benefiting from a feature, such as Expertise, that doubles your proficiency bonus.

If my PC isn't proficient in say *Survival*, and chooses it for point 1, can I then choose *Survival* again for point 2, effectively going from no proficiency to expertise in a single feat?

I would think so given *"Choose one skill in which you have proficiency"* but I'm not sure it applies yet given it's not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes.

Once you have the Prodigy feat, you have that additional skill proficiency. Thus, you can have expertise in that skill as well. The two occur simultaneously, but nothing prevents you choosing the new skill proficiency for your expertise as well.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. You only state that *after* taking the feat the character can gain expertise. The problem is whether the bonuses of the feat are applied sequentially or simultaneously.

Comment: They are simultaneous.

Comment: That contradicts your answer.

Comment: @Szega: Not really. You gain both benefits at once. You gain a skill proficiency, and you gain expertise in a skill you're proficient in. Given that these benefits occur at the same time, not one after the other, you could choose to make your choices in any order. There is nothing preventing you from picking the same skill to gain proficiency in and to gain expertise (or double proficiency, rather) in.

Comment: That is what sequential is: one after the other. If they happen at the same time, one cannot depend on the other. Nevertheless, I know of no rule or errata that would support either way of thinking.